# error with custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting this error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x5a37750> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key destination.'
```

Following is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReservationCell";

    ReservationCell *cell = (ReservationCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReservationCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (ReservationCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    //cell.origin.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] origin];
    //cell.destination.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] destination]; 
    //cell.time_range.text = [[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time_range]; 

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the ReservationCell.h

```
@interface ReservationCell : UITableViewCell {
    UILabel * origin;
    UILabel * destination;
    UILabel * time_range;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * origin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * destination;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * time_range;

@end
```

Here's how I wired it up:
[image]

Comment: have you set the identifier of the cell ?

Comment: via IB you mean? yes I did that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReservationCell"
                                                         owner:nil 
                                                       options:nil];
```

Is setting the Files Owner to nil. So you can't wire any of your labels to that. Instead, make sure the class of the cell is `ReservationCell` and its outlets are connected to the labels.

Comment: it breaks down on this line:
 NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReservationCell" owner:nil options:nil];

Comment: How have you wired up the UILabel outlets in the NIB? To the cell?

Comment: added a picture above to show how I wired it.. and yes I did wire it up

Comment: the files owner is nil in your example. wire them to the cell...  It looks like you set the files owner to ReservationCell. Instead set the class of the cell to ReservationCell and wire the labels to that.

Comment: I fixed it.. I wrongly wired from the File's Owner to the Cell not from the objects

Comment: It doesn't matter since you aren't going to use it

Answer (score 10):

For someone, who already reached to this thread and not able to figure out the solution like me, here is the quick solution to this problem:

**In interface builder you linked your IBOutlets from File's Owner when you should link them from the cell view. This is why you are getting the errors.**

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I would've never figured that out myself.

Answer (score 7):

This problem happen when in the interface builder for the CustomCell nib, the File's Owner custom class is set to your CustomCell class.

1. File's owner custom class should be set always UITableViewCell.
2. Table view object custom class should be set to your CustomCell class.

Also you need to initialize it with Nib name of your tableview cell.

Example (NotificationCell is my custom cell class):
http://i42.tinypic.com/29pw0a8.png

Answer (score 4):

My exception was 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key (and name label which I had on the CustomCell, I got this error only when I added something in CustomCell e.g. label)

**Solution problem** my friend gave me great advice add MyCustomCell.m add to the **ProjectSettings -> Build Phases -> add MyCustomCell.m file**

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had added the interface for the cell to the header file but did not have an implementation in the .m file.  Simply adding an empty implementation (as below) for the class to the .m file fixed the problem.

```
@implementation myTableViewCell
@end
```

Surprised this has not been listed as an answer as this has bitten me several times in the past.  Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had duplicated a prototype cell in storyboard and deleted one of the outlets in the cell. It left a reference to the outlet but not connected to anything. Right-click on the prototype cell and look for one of those yellow warning markers.