# Error with custom UITableViewCell and IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, xib

I start by saying that I'm not sure if what I'm doing is the best way for that.
I have the following scenario: a dynamic grouped `TableView` with two groups, the first has a static cell and the second has a dynamic cell populated by an array.
The second group works fine, the first is not!

The first group has only one custom cell that i load with this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...

    if (indexPath.section == kSectionHeader) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActorDetailsHeaderCell" owner:self options:nil];
        ActorDetailsHeaderCell * headerCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        headerCell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.actor.image];
        headerCell.actorName.text = self.actor.name;
        headerCell.info.text = @"";

        return headerCell;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `ActorDetailsHeaderCell.xib` file has a custom class named `ActorDetailsHeaderCell` that extends `UITableViewCell` class.
If I leave everything like this (just for test purpose) everything works fine, as soon as I set an `IBOutlet`in `ActorDetailsHeaderCell.h` file I get this error:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ActorDetailsViewController 0x7485a60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

I found on Stackoverflow those questions: [iPhone: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015419/iphone-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) and [error with custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343172/error-with-custom-uitableviewcell), but those answers don't seem to solve my problem.
I tried to delete the `.xib` and the class and rewrite them from scratch but it that damn error is always there!

I end up by saying that the SAME thing is used in other `UITableViewController` and it works fine!

Comment: Your error states that ActorDetailsViewController doesn't respond to the key in question, but you say you're trying to set a value on your ActorDetailsHeaderCell.

That error seems to be saying that you're trying to set a value on the wrong object, perhaps?

Comment: As you can see in my code, I'm trying to set a value on `headerCell` that is a `ActorDetailsHeaderCell` object, it's not a `ActorDetailsViewController`. This thing is freaking me out!

Comment: Perhaps you've got an object in your ActorDetailsHeaderCell.xib that's trying to set a value on File Owner (which, in this case, is your viewController), but the viewController doesn't have an IBOutlet setup for that.

Comment: If you comment out the  headerCell.actorName.text = self.actor.name; line does it work? Also, what do you mean by "as soon as I set an IBOutlet in ActorDetailsHeaderCell.h file I get this error" -- what outlet are you adding?

Comment: If I comment out that line it doesn't work neither. What I mean with that is that if I don't connect any IBOutlet (1 UIImage and 2 UILabel s) from xib to class' header no error message comes out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why today everything works!
I closed  the project yesterday evening and there was that error, this morning the app works!

I think is an xcode bug... I don't know! Thanks any way